# Регистрация/авторизация ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Начал изучать ASP.NET MVS (NET.FRAMEWORK), и тут же столкнулся с проблемой. Создавал проект MVC с авторизацией и регистрацией(гугл, твиттер и т.п). При запуске готового шаблона и попытке регистрации, вылазит следующая ошибка. Может кто знает как ее решить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Шаблон никак не изменял.

Comment: а) укажите что за шаблон вы использовали, версию visual studio б) покажите ваш коннекшн стринг б) попробуйте подцепиться к установленному SQL сервер

Comment: ошибка скорее всего связана с подключением к базе: проверьте подключение и убедитесь, что база доступна

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20190725105003.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20190725105003;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
Моя строка подключения. Пробовал подключится к установленному SQL Server, выбило ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильно указан `connectionStrings`

Строка подключения зависит от библиотек которые вы используете и какой тип базы вы подключаете.

Стандартное подключение базы данных(эта строка указана с свойствах самой базы):

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Players;Integrated Security=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

или так если конектите mdf файл:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionName"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

если обмен данными с базой происходит через `EntityFramework`:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Oauth_APIEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AdoEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.AdoEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.AdoEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DB_Oauth_API.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

`AdoEntityModel.csdl , AdoEntityModel.ssdl , AdoEntityModel.msl` это ресурсы

Вообщем вариантов подключения может быть множество. Советую Вам показать вашу строку подключения в файле `Web.config` вашего проекта.

Хороший вариант по которому ранее делал я [WebApiOAuth2](https://github.com/TheCoder87/WebApiOAuth2)

Comment: Вот моя строка подключения @Артур Франк
`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20190725105003.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20190725105003;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: С помощью какого фреймворка вы получаете данные? EntityFramework? если через него то эта строка работать не будет. К тому же в этой строке подключения `Initial Catalog` лишний. Если ничего не получится скиньте гайды по которым вы все это делали.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=tTTXvIjkQiw Вот по этому гайду. Но, я же говорю, я ничего не менял, это чистый, только что созданный шаблон, и он не работает.

Comment: И да, там имеется EntityFramework, но я не знаю, задействован он или нет.

Comment: Пробежался по видеогайду который вы предоставили... действительно, фреймворк который используется в том гайде самостоятельно создает строку подключения. Но все же, попробуйте заменить установленную строку подключения той которая указанна в самой БД. Нажимаете 2 раза ЛКМ по вашей базе данных и в свойствах БД, копируете строку подключения и заменяете ее в файле Web.config

И учитывайте то что когда вы опубликуете ваш проект строка подключения нужна будет совершенно другая.

Comment: Не понял где получить строку, где нужно нажать 2 раза ЛКМ, в менеджере серверов в VS, или где то в SQL Managment Studio?

Comment: https://ibb.co/Y83vqvy

Comment: Разобрался с ситуцией, проблема в криво установленном SQL Server